# What functions satisfy $f(x+1)+f(x-1)=x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, periodic-functions

What functions satisfy $f(x+1)+f(x-1)=x$?

If we consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$, then we have $f(x+1)+f(x-1)=x$ . I tried to replace $x$ by $x+1, x-1$ in the equality,to get  $f(x)$ but without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the best I hope $f$ can be determined by its value on $[0,1]$. The value inside may be arbitrary.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ does the trick. You have that $f(x+1)+f(x-1)=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}=x$

Comment: The set of function verifying that is isomorphic to the set of functions on $[0,2[$ or any interval of length $2$, just try to compute $f(x+2)$ from $f(x)$ and iterate

Comment: Another example:  $$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)+\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: @MathFall I like your deleted answer. Could you  correct it along the lines in the comments and undelete it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have found a specific solution $f(x)=\frac12x$, let $f(x)=\frac12x+g(x)$, we get

$$g(x+1)+g(x-1)=0\Longrightarrow g(x)=-g(x+2)$$

therefore, any functions
$$f(x)=\frac12x+g(x)$$

will satisfy your equation, where $g(x)=-g(x+2)$.

Comment: I think $g(x) = g(x+4)$ does not imply $g(x) = -g(x+2)$.

Comment: Any function satisfying $g(x+2)=-g(x),$ as not every function with period $4$ satisfies the first condition

Comment: Right, I have edited it, thank you!

Comment: I'd add that $g(x)$ is called "antiperiodic" (period $2$) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntiperiodicFunction.html
And that this cover the full set of solutions.

Comment: Nice answer (+)

Comment: Very nice! thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many such functions. Specify the value of $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ on the interval $[0, 2)$. Then, define

$$f (x) = 2 \left\lfloor \frac{x}{4} \right\rfloor + h \left( x - 4 \left\lfloor \frac{x}{4} \right\rfloor \right)$$

where $h : [0, 4) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$$h (y) = \begin{cases}
f (y) & y \in [0, 2) \\
y - 1 - f (y - 2) & y \in [2, 4)
\end{cases}$$

for all $x \notin [0, 2)$.